# If statement inside select clause (postgresql)

Tags: sql, postgresql, greenplum

I want to set 0 or 1 flag based on column value.if the value is > 0.0 AND <= 99.0 then 1 ,else 0 .

```
              Score         flag_score

              0.083642      1
              0.009542      1
              0.999999      1
              101.0000      0
```

Comment: `select score Score, case when score > 0.0 AND score <= 99.0 then 1 else 0 end flag_score from table;`

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried `case` expression ?

```
select *, 
        (case when value > 0.0 and value <= 99.0 then 1 else 0 end) flag_score
from table;
```

Comment: Case statement works..But cant we write if statement for the above case

Comment: @user8545255 No. There is no `if` statement in the SQL standard.

Comment: @user8545255: You could write your own `if()` function if it'd made you happy.

Answer (score 1):

I would write this simply as:

```
select t.*, ( (value > 0.0) and (value <= 99.0) )::int as flag_score
from t;
```

Postgres has a nice shorthand for declaring flags, so `case` expressions are not needed.

If you want to actually set the value, you can do:

```
update t
    set flag = ( (value > 0.0) and (value <= 99.0) )::int;
```